# Making a background 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter

I have an image that is 1600x1200px, I'm trying to do the "twitter background effect" (where the image is fixed and does not repeat) , but a bit differently.

I know you can just set the image in the body as such:

```
    background: url("background1.jpg") no-repeat fixed center #000;
```

or

```
    background: url("background1.jpg") no-repeat fixed 0 0 #000;
```

as twitter does it

However, then, the full height of the image does not show. The width is fine.
I want the image to be 1200px long, so the full height of the image is shown.

Is there any way to do this?

To make it a bit clearer, I drew this extremely detailed diagram in GIMP:

[image]

Comment: `background-size: 100% 100%` for modern browsers

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this:

http://bavotasan.com/downloads/full-sizebackground-image-jquery-plugin/

By using:

```
background-image: url(your-bg-image.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center center;
background-attachment:fixed;
-o-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
}
```

Comment: It's a very bad idea to depend on javascript for the OP purposes.  I disagree that this will work across all browsers.

Comment: The code posted above, doesnt rely on js, its pure css. The link however is jquery.

Comment: the edit was done 41 mins ago, your reply 35 mins ago. :) your welcome

Comment: I'm glad you've noticed and included in your edit, but you need to re-read the OP and provide a solution for the specified problem, not the one you know to solve.

Answer (score 0):

CSS only, very clean and actually well done:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3/f/blfaqbgsize.htm

Comment: What good is this if/when the link goes dead?  Please provide a more _self-contained_ answer.